# jQuery .animate() control issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am using the below formula animate a div with the class 'box' to the center of my page (this works).

```
    var $box = $('div.box'), 
    $W = $(window).width() / 2 - $box.outerWidth() / 2,
    $H = $(window).height() / 2 - $box.outerHeight() / 2;

$('button.increase').on('click', function(){
    $box
    .css({
        'left': $W,
        'position':'absolute'
    })

    .animate({
    'top': $H,
    }, { duration: 2000, queue: false}); 


    });
```

I would now like to animate the div with the class 'box' back to the default position. I thought by reversing the mathematic operators I could accomplish this like so

```
$DW = $(window).width() * 2 + $box.outerWidth() * 2,
$DH = $(window).height() * 2 + $box.outerHeight() * 2;
```

but it does not work.

Comment: just keep initial position inside data object relative to element, e.g: `$box.data('offset', $box.offset());`. In order to get more help, you should provide a jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Your math is wrong, try

```
$DW = $(window).width() / 2 - $box.outerWidth() / 2,
$DH = $(window).height() / 2 - $box.outerHeight() * 2;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r9Jya/)

This maintains the box's x position, and just changes the y to where it was at the start (*2).

Comment: It is working in the demo you provided, but when i apply the changes to $DH the div top decrease to -443px making it invisible in the browser window.

Comment: @user1584751 Do you mind telling me the code you have for returning the box to its normal position?

Comment: $DW = $(window).width() / 2 - $box.outerWidth() / 2,
$DH = $(window).height() / 2 - $box.outerHeight() * 2;

Comment: @user1584751 No, I mean what is the function you execute that moves it back

Comment: Sorry about that. Here is the function I am using. - $('button.decrease').on('click', function(){
   $box.css({
    'left': $DW,
    'position':'absolute'
   })

   .animate({
    'top': $DH,
   },{ duration: 2000, queue: false});
  });